# How to know if a WCF is compatible with java (without having the code)

Tags: java, wcf

I have a WCF webservice that i should use from a java client.
I never worked with WCF or webservices, so how do i know first if it is written in a way compatible with java client(if i can know from the wsdl for example).

When generating the client from Eclipse. i get MyWcfServiceLocator and MyWcf. MyWcf has no methods

Thank you

Comment: which java framework do you use - axis, wsit, xfire etc?

Comment: Its axis. Quick question, does the wsdl have to be flatened?

Comment: generally axis should support it even if it is not flat. but worth a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable non WCF clients the WCF service should expose the endpoint over basicHttpBinding which is the binding provided by microsoft for maximum interoperability. If the endpoint is exposed over wsHttpBinding (which is kind of a default IIRC) this could cause you some problems.

Comment: It's difficult. You should talk to the vendors of the service and ask them.

Comment: I already did, In fact your answer was the solution they proposed.

Answer (score 1):

You should be just working with the provided wsdl and the the endpoint associated for the same. You really need not bother about the server side implementation, it will definitely cater to the wsdl provided.

Comment: With the help of wsdl you can develop your java client. Further, you can override the endpoint in your code based on the different target environment. You can use any thirdparty libraries such as Apache cxf, to generate your java client. Hope it helps.  [CXF - Wsdl2Java](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html)

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i already generated my java client. But there is something wrong (there are no methods to call) so I wanted to check if there is something wrong from the serve side.